# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, ca, jks

I'm having a jar in which needs to get an instance from a REST API. I have done the SSL certificate set up and have generated the private key and public key as JKS. I have imported my certificate to Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\security\cacerts.It worked for one way authentication. But after I have changed to two-way authentication, I'm getting fatal alert: bad_certificate error.

I'm getting error in the line Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

```
WebTarget target = cp.getClient()
            .target("https://" + cp.getServerIp() + ":" + cp.getRestAPIPort() + "/product-info").path("");
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target
            .request(new String[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.toString() });
    invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cp.getAccessToken());
    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

ERROR RESPONSE:

```
    javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:753)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:752)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:419)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:319)
        at com.p3.ca.ia.rest.RestLayerActivities.getInstanceInformation(RestLayerActivities.java:108)
        at com.p3.ca.ia.rest.IaRestMain.begin(IaRestMain.java:87)
        at com.p3.ca.CaIaApplication.main(CaIaApplication.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1761)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1152)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1280)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1190)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:369)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:390)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: The server does not like the client certificate. It is unknown what the requirements are for this certificate and there is nothing known about your client certificates which means that it is completely unclear for us what the server does not like. Thus, look at the server side for any error logs, look at the requirements the server has regarding client certificates (i.e. issued by a specific CA, containing a specific subject, specific key usage ...) and then check if the client certificate you send matches the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the server does not trust you client side certificate for CA.